# write to two outputs at once in spark2

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I need to write to two outputs at once in spark2.
I tried something like this:

```
    Dataset<Row> streamedData = spark.readStream().schema(getSchema())
            .json("src/test/data")
            .filter(x->{
                System.out.println("this is some fitler operation");
                return true;
            });

    StreamingQuery streamingQueury = streamedData
            .writeStream()
            .format("memory")
            .queryName("streameddata")
            .start();

    StreamingQuery streamingQueury2 = streamedData
            .writeStream()
            .format("console")
            .start();

    streamingQueury.awaitTermination(1000);
    streamingQueury2.awaitTermination(1000);
    streamingQueury.stop();
    streamingQueury2.stop();

    spark.sql("SELECT * FROM streameddata").show();
```

this will do what i need but it will execute whole chain two times what can be time consuming, i don't need to do all the transformations two times i just need to write it two times.

Is there a way for me?

Thanks